# How to get key values from JsonObj

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a `json` object like this actually it is coming dynamically. 
For example we can use this Json object.

```
var JsonObj= { "one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5 };
```

But i want to change it some thing like this using `javascript` or `jquery`.

```
var sample = [

 {
  "label":"one",
  "value":1
 },

 {
  "label":"two",
  "value":2
 },
 {
  "label":"three",
  "value":3
 },
 { 
  "label":"four",
  "value":4
 },
 { 
  "label":"five",
  "value":5
  }

 ];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var JsonObj= { "one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5 };
var arr = [];
for(property in JsonObj) {
    arr.push(
             {"label":property, 
             "value":JsonObj[property]})
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the `Object.keys` method

`var keys = Object.keys(myJSONObject);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but pawel answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertToLabelValue(object){
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function(acc,label){
        acc.push({
            "label": label,
            "value": object[label]
        });
        return acc;
    },[]);
}
```

Usage:

```
convertToLabelValue({ "one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5 })
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "label": "one",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "label": "two",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "label": "three",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "label": "four",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "label": "five",
    "value": 5
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it with JQuery try below:

```
var JsonObj= { "one":1, "two":2, "three":3, "four":4, "five":5 };
var sample = [];
$.each(JsonObj, function(key, val){
    sample.push({'label': key, 'value': val});
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/c6ojsb6c/2/

Hit f12 to see the console for final JSON.